# Border style Group

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to apply a bottom border to my report based on the first group.
Below is my matrix in the report.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH2Cc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eRL6.png)

Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards

I want to change it below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkX7c.png)
I like to have it like red lines and all vertical lines.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following sample dataset

```
select 'rg1' as rowgroup1, 'rg1.1' as rowgroup2   union all
select 'rg1' as rowgroup1, 'rg1.2' as rowgroup2   union all
select 'rg2' as rowgroup1, 'rg2.1' as rowgroup2   union all
select 'rg2' as rowgroup1, 'rg2.2' as rowgroup2   union all
select 'rg2' as rowgroup1, 'rg2.3' as rowgroup2   union all
select 'rg3' as rowgroup1, 'rg3.1' as rowgroup2   union all
select 'rg4' as rowgroup1, 'rg4.1' as rowgroup2   union all
select 'rg4' as rowgroup1, 'rg4.2' as rowgroup2   union all
select 'rg4' as rowgroup1, 'rg4.3' as rowgroup2
```

[image]

The borders for rowgroup1 are set to red

For rowgroup2: Borders set to solid except the top border which is set to none. The default border color is set to black, but for the bottom border color you use an expression which conditionally sets the border to red if it is the last line of the group.

[image]

To achieve this you use an expression that checks if the current line is the last in the group

```
= Iif( CountRows("rowgroup1") = RunningValue(Fields!rowgroup2.Value, Count,"rowgroup1"), "Red", "Black")
```

[image]